# Sharing Global Menu Links Menu to subsites

Tags: 7, routes, domain-access, database

How to present a global menu across multiple subsites

I've been trawling the Drupal site for answers to this and because I'm only 4 days into my Drupal 7 adventure I'm sure half my battle is finding the right words to say to the community to get what I'm asking for.

This question seems to hit the mark http://drupal.org/node/1428516

But the only answer is something about Domain Access http://drupal.org/project/domain but that looks pretty complicated when all I want to do is to splat a small block of html at the top of all my sites.

So I'm thinking the architecture would be something like this.

```
master site
+ - menu-global-menu    
+ - global-menu-module (looks in master site db for menu-global-menu 
                        and fills variable $global_menu) 
+ - corporate theme (requires global-menu-module)
|
+ - > subsite 1
+ - inherits corporate theme
|
+ - > subsite 2
+ - inherits corporate theme
```

Does this make sense? Or should I be achieving this some other way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I think I've gone a long way to achieving this.

In the setting.php file of each site I declare a Data Connection called globalmenu that point's to the database belong to the menu's management site.

I make the menu and get the machine name for it; in my case menu-global-menu.

In my page.tpl.php of my theme I have included this

```
  <?php 
  if ($global_menu){
  print($global_menu);
  }
  ?>
```

My module

```
function global_header_preprocess_page(&$variables, $hook) {

 $query_options['target'] = 'globalmenu';   

 $query = db_select('menu_links', 'p', $query_options)
    ->fields('p')
    ->condition('menu_name', 'menu-global-menu', '=')
    ->execute();

 if($query->rowCount() ==   0) {
    print '<div class="messages error"><em>No Global Header Configured!</em><ul><li>Check the Global Header Module Help for details</li><ul>   </div>';
}

 $links = array();  
 $markup = "<div class='global-navigation'><ul class='nav'>";

 foreach ($query as $item) {    
    $markup = $markup ."<li><a href='".$item->link_path."' class='global-link'>".$item->link_title."</a></li>";
 }  

 $markup = $markup ."</ul></div>";  
 $variables['global_menu'] = $markup;
}
```

There's probably a much better way of doing the markup but I'm a noob so I guess someone will correct me.